# Ajuda com view laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Preciso mostrar duas categorias em uma `view`. Tentei da forma abaixo, porém sem sucesso:

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('Titles.IndexFutebol')->withType('time1')->withType('time2');

}
```

somente mostra `type time2`.

Comment: Qual a versão do Laravel?

Comment: versão do laravel é 4.2

Comment: Já tentou com `View::make('Titles.IndexFutebol')->with('time1', $time1)->with('time2', $time2);` ?

Comment: public function index()
 {
  
$time1= \Title::where('type', 'atletico');
$time2= \Title::where('type', 'cruzeiro');
  
  
  return View::make('Titles.IndexFutebol')->with('type', $time1)->with('type', $time2);
  
  
 }

Comment: e assim app.viewModels.titles.index.start('cruzeiro','atletico');

Comment: Você não pode repetir o nome `type`

Comment: return View::make('Titles.IndexFutebol')->with('type', $time1,$time2); só mostra $time2

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que eu li nos comentários você está usando a versão 4.2 do laravel (não considera dá um upgrade?).

Tenta assim:

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('Titles.IndexFutebol')->with('type', $time1, $time2);

}
```